# IntelliJ Optimize Imports for the entire scala project

Tags: intellij-idea

One of the very useful features of IntelliJ is that when I am done editing a file, I can do a "optimize imports". this removes all the unused imports from my code.

This is very useful, but I have to do it for every file.

Can I do "optimize imports" for the entire project?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Select the source root in the project tree;

**1. Hit the keyboard shortcut for "*Optimize import*"**

**MAC**

```
Cmd-shift-A
```

**Windows**

```
Ctrl-shift-A
```

**2. You will see**

[image: dialog of auto import]

**3. Hit Run**

Comment: Nice, even recurses down into every dir and also provides an option to only do this on changed VCS files

Comment: Excellent. I had no idea that running `Optimize Imports` after clicking on root would make a difference. 

Just a word of advice to other developers landing in this answer, check your actual optimize imports short cut on `Code > Optimize Imports` tab –– Mine was `cmd + opt + o` :)

Comment: "Select the source root in the project tree;" this should be in bold

Answer (score 1):

First you build the project, In "build output" tab in left bottom corner, you will see lot of files with compilation errors. Select them all and press CRTL+ALT+O

A popup will open which will ask "Optimize import for 'module'"

Click Run.

Answer (score 0):

Select your project -> right click -> Optimize import
Notice!:
You can do that for all file in project/module or just for uncommitted changes.

[image]